# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'rowguid', column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I avoid this problem:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'rowguid', column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Sample query is:

```
insert into tablename (col1, col2, col3)  
values('v1', 'v2', 'v3')
```

Comment: Well, presumably there is a column `rowguid` . Does it allow nulls? Des it have a default value? If you answered "no" and "no" (to the last two questions), where are you expecting it to get a value from?

Answer (score 3):

If you are not going to insert the value explicitly in the INSERT statement, and the columns is [NOT NULL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_notnull.asp), you need to specify a [default](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp) value in the TABLE.

> The DEFAULT constraint is used to insert a default value into a
>   column.   The default value will be added to all new records, if no
>   other value is specified.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your table has been created with a ROWGUIDCOL but without the appropriate default value. Here is an example from ASP.NET forum for a proper table definition using the feature. It should give you some help.

```
CREATE TABLE Globally_Unique_Data
 (guid uniqueidentifier CONSTRAINT Guid_Default DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() ROWGUIDCOL,
 Employee_Name varchar(60)
 CONSTRAINT Guid_PK PRIMARY KEY (Guid) );
```

The NEWSEQUENTIALID() default will generate a GUID for you. Without it you will have to generate your own and include it in the insert. You don't have to use it as the primary key as in the example, but you have to supply it or use the default.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions to this problem.

One you can make column 'rowguid' to allow null and the other is to set some default value of your parameters.

In your code you can set values as

```
int v1 = 0;
string v2 ="";
```

Then pass these values to query.

You can set default parameter values in the stored procedure as

```
@v1 int = 0,
@v2 varchar(50) = ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Files](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdFile] [uniqueidentifier] unique ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [File] [varbinary](max) FILESTREAM  NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
))
```